# Using Python to download excel attachments in outlook

Tags: python, imaplib

I have tried researching this but a lot of the times it is for Gmail and for other online services and the ones I did find that sort of meet my needs they were quite a few years old and didn't work:

[Downloading multiple attachments using imaplib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225763/downloading-multiple-attachments-using-imaplib) --- 9 years old
[Downloading excel attachments using imaplib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48445618/downloading-excel-attachments-using-imaplib) --- nearly 3 years old

The https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html was quite insightful but wasn't able to implement what I had learned.

Tried manipulating the code to fit my requirements but keep getting errors:

```
    m.login(user, password)
  File "C:\Users\uk20071143\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\imaplib.py", line 603, in login
    raise self.error(dat[-1])
imaplib.IMAP4.error: b'LOGIN failed.'
```

Currently, I have an excel that has been sent out to project managers where once they press submit I am sent an email with the work they want to be submitted, because of the changes that are usually made I leave combining them to the end.

Using python I am trying to automate downloading the Excel attachments from all emails that have a subject name of Matrix to a designated folder where I run another piece of VBA code that will pull the newest files into one output excel.

I am using Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus, I was trying with the default folder numbers but didn't work, not sure whether this was correct but Inbox [6]??

Annoyingly only ever seem to find perfect Gmail codes: https://gist.github.com/baali/2633554

```
    server = 'outlook.office365.com'
    user = input('email: ')
    password = ('password: ')
    outputdir = 'C:/Users'
    subject = 'Matrix'

def connect(server, user, password):
    conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(server)
    conn.login(user, password)
    conn.select()
    return conn
```

Above is the sort of way I want to connect but it fails to output anything when testing or it just fails.

If anyone has a code or any idea on how to download attachments from outlook using python that using the subject and subject body 'Matrix' as reference. well that would be amazing

Thanks

Comment: @Davidsherriff Do you have an idea on this at all?

Comment: Has your admin enabled IMAP login?  Plain login will be disabled on Office35 shortly, if it hasn’t already, and you would have to use OAuth. They reaallllly do not want people to be using basic passwords with O365.

Comment: Ahh okay thank you @Max Can i ask how this would be done?

Comment: @Ooo Did you ever receive a good answer to this? Same thing over here.